# VLC player is not opening in my ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: video, vlc, multimedia, video-player, media

```
 ~ $ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.6 Vetinari (revision 3.0.6-0-g5803e85)
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
[0000000001174be0] skins2 interface error: unable to attach stream_directory, treat as XML!
[0000000001174be0] skins2 interface error: no XML found in theme /home/karmoksh/Downloads/Wallpaper/90's-kid-3840×2160.jpg
[00007f7dd003b670] xml xml reader error: XML parser error (line 1) : Document is empty

[0000000001174be0] skins2 interface error: no skins found : exiting
```

This is the second time when this is happening. First time I reinstalled it and it worked fine but again it's not working.

Comment: What does `apt policy vlc` show?

Comment: You might try to remove the config files for vlc, something like `mv ~/.config/vlc ~/.config/vlc.bak` would cause vlc to regenerate the configurations.

Comment: @DKBose  {$ apt policy vlc
vlc:
  Installed: 3.0.4-1ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 3.0.4-1ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.4-1ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.pramati.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.3-1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirror.pramati.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://mirror.pramati.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages}

Comment: @CharlesGreen { mv ~/.config/vlc 
mv: missing destination file operand after '/home/********/.config/vlc'
Try 'mv --help' for more information. } It's not working.

Comment: @Huxoor You need to provide two arguements for 'mv' the first being the file to move, the second being the destination.  The command that I posted has 'vlc' as the file to move, followed by a space, and the destination which is 'vlc.bak'